# Get minimum and maximum of object property names that are integers

Tags: javascript

**UPDATED**  (formulated the problem wrong, see note below)

I have an object that has a set of properties that are named with numbers as shown in the example. The 'numbered names' are not necessarily consecutive, nor do I know where they start or end. I do know that other properties will not be named with numbers.
I know that myObject["propName"] is the same as myObject.propName, but I deliberately write it in the first way because myObject.0 looks weird and doesn't get recognized by all editors.

How do I get the min- and maximum array index?

So in a situation like this

```
myObject["0"] = undefined
myObject["1"] = {}
myObject["2"] = undefined
myObject["3"] = {}
myObject["4"] = {}
myObject["5"] = undefined
myObject["someOtherProperty"] = {}
```

would give me this

```
minIndex(myObject) == 1
maxIndex(myObject) == 4
```

**To all the answers before this edit**
Thanks for your replies. I shouldn't have posted this question in a hurry and should have re-read it before committing. It was late and I was in a hurry. My apologies.
By actually seeing my wrong statement (using an array instead of an object) I think that, based on answers for my reformulated problem, I might need to rewrite my code to use an array instead of an object. The reason I'm using an object rather then an array is material for another question.

**Efforts so far**
I have tried finding a way of converting the property names to an array and then looping through them, but that has proven cludgy. I'm kind of looking for a less error-prone and elegant way.

Comment: By the way... you can remove items from an array without the ugly holes with array.splice(). Maybe this eradicates the question in the first place.

Comment: I would close the question. These types of questions, besides not showing any research effort, always end up in a Crazy Coding Contest (C3). There is not enough time on Earth to correct everything in all the answers, and if I downvote most of them for various reasons, angry townspeople might attack my home.

Comment: Wow, haven't looked this for a workday and then this. Quite shocked. Yes, I'm quite new to real javascript. Furthermore I think that, in my effort to give only the core problem, I might have boiled the question down incorrect and posed the problem wrong. I'm going to try and review the entire thing. But really: ouch

Comment: @Esailija, you are right to question this. Reformulated question, added response to you request in OP

Comment: @BorisCallens ah it's not an array at all, interesting.

Comment: @Boris Callens I updated my answer. Let me know if this works given the "updated scenario" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myObject = {};
myObject["0"] = undefined;
myObject["1"] = {};
myObject["2"] = undefined;
myObject["3"] = {};
myObject["4"] = {};
myObject["5"] = undefined;
myObject["someOtherProperty"] = {};

var keys = Object.keys(myObject).map(Number).filter(function(a){
    return isFinite(a) && myObject[a];
});

var min = Math.min.apply(Math, keys);
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, keys);

console.log(min, max); //Logs 1 and 4
```

Documentation and compatibility information for all:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: This looks nice and tidy :) Had seen a post from John Resig about using apply for max. This incorporates it nicely. Had some concerns about compatibility, but the links seem to solve it. Nice and thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

**Edit**: Aha! Now the problem becomes more interesting.

*Solution 1:* Let's solve this in one shot, shall we? For max:

```
function maxIndex(obj){
    var max = -1;
    for(var i in myObject){
        var val = parseInt(i);
        if(isFinite(val)){
            if(typeof obj[val] !== 'undefined' && val > max){
                max = val;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I think you can convert this to min on your own ;)

*Solution 2*: Here I'll your *object* back into what we originally thought it was, in case you really loved one of the other solutions. Then the rest of the answer applies.

```
function convertObject(obj){
    var output = [];
    for(var i in myObject){
        var val = parseInt(i);
        if(isFinite(val)){         
            output[val] = obj[i]; //Gotta love JS
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Continue as planned!

---

To find the smallest, begin at the bottom and work your way up until you find it.

```
function minIndex(myArray){
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        if(typeof myArray[i] !== 'undefined')
            return i;
    }
}
```

To get the biggest, start at the top.

```
function maxIndex(myArray){
    for(var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(typeof myArray[i] !== 'undefined')
            return i;
    }
}
```

Both are worst case O(n). You can't really do better because the whole array could be empty, and you'd have to check every element to be positive.

Edit: As is mentioned, you can also check if something is *not* undefined by simply writing `if(myArray[i])`. Whatever suits your fancy.

Comment: `null == undefined`... I don't get why not people simply use `typeof x == 'undefined'`, which is a proven way for testing for `undefined`.

Comment: if we're going to use != might as well use if(myArray[i]) and second if you're worried about performance just use a single loop and return {min:1, max:4}

Comment: @bažmegakapa Simply rushed it is all. I've been jumping between a lot of languages today ^.^

Comment: @LiviuT. Re: O(1) solution, nice try, but if you read the question carefully it mentions that the slots are randomly filled or not.

Comment: @ngmiceli One more thing: `!` has a higher precedence than `===`. I suggest using `!==` instead.

Comment: And concerning your edit: `if (myArray[i])` is a very bad idea. It gives false for `undefined` - and for all the falsy values also.

Comment: @ngmiceli i din't mention O(1) :). I meant if you don't want 2xO(n) you could merge the functions in one

Comment: @LiviuT. Ah! My apologies, I thought you were suggesting returning a constant value, answering the *exact* problem he mentioned above. Yes, you are completely correct, but its technically not what the OP asked for :)

Comment: Beware of != since it does type coersion. JSLint doesn't allow it, for good reason. I disagree with JSLint's nazi enforcement of spacing and style that I don't like, but it's a great tool otherwise.

Comment: `!= null` is legit and robust. It's not the same as checking for falsy values, it's the same as `!== null && !== undefined` which is exactly what you want in a broken language with 2 types of undefined values. Use `in` or `.hasOwnProperty` to check for existence as `undefined` can be a value of a key. Otherwise, `!= null/undefined` does the job.

Comment: Thanks for the reviewed solution. This was kind of what I tried by myself ('xcept mine wasn't compiling ;). @Esailija's solution is more the succint, clean and tidy syntax I was aiming for though. Thank both for your patience with my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through the array until you find the 1st non-`undefined` element.

```
function minIndex(arr){
    for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
        if(arr[i] !== undefined){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

For max index, do the same thing, except in reverse.

```
function maxIndex(arr){
    for(var i = arr.length-1, len = 0; i >= len; i--){
        if(arr[i] !== undefined){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't the maxIndex one throw an index out of bounds exception when trying to access `arr[arr.length]` or would the undefined catch it?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: The `undefined` would catch it, but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Min:

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if(myArray[i] != undefined) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Max:

```
for(var i = myArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(myArray[i] != undefined) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
function minIndex(var array){
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   {
      if(typeof array[i] != "undefined")
      return i;
   }
   return null;
}

function maxIndex(var array){
   var returnIndex = -1;
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   {
      if(typeof array[i] != "undefined")
      returnIndex = i;
   }
   if(returnIndex !== -1) return returnIndex;
   else return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var max=0;
var min=myArray.length;
for (var i in myArray)
    if (myArray[i]!==undefined)
    {
        max=Math.max(i, max);
        min=Math.min(i, min);
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `for...in` for arrays.  Plus since the values are explicitly set to `undefined` all the keys will appear here.

Comment: You'd have to test for the values of course, but the for...in method has the advantage of checking only defined values, not all possible values starting from 0.

Comment: Problem is, in the example, all the values *are* defined.  Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays

Comment: Edited to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes... I was trying to avoid having to run through 1000 elements if we have an array like this: var a=[]; a[1000]=5;.

Comment: I think the downvotes are because it's frowned upon to use `for...in` on arrays.

Comment: Yes, but why is it frowned upon in this specific case?

Comment: I've just always learned never to use `for...in` on arrays.  P.S. I didn't downvote.

Comment: @WolfgangStengel Rocket already posted an interesting link about why not to use it for arrays. `myArray.x = 1` would simply cause your code to result in `x` for the max - even though that is not part of the array itself. This leads to hours of debugging in certain cases - which can simply be avoided by sticking to best practices. The check for `undefined` can also be improved, but I would not downvote for that.

Answer (score -1):

this takes advantage of the fact that for..in only iterates over defined elements, and uses the index:

```
function minIndex(arr){ for(el in arr){return el} }

function maxIndex(arr){var v; for(el in arr){v = el}; return v }
```

CAVEATS:
The second function is not very efficient though, since it loops through the entire array.
This wont work if you are EXPLICITLY setting the undefined indexes.

Comment: In the example. the values are literally defined as `undefined`, so this won't work.  Plus you shouldn't use `for...in` for Arrays.

Comment: Just realized about the explicit definitions. I tried it by just adding the defined values. I'm lazy (which is a cardinal virtue of programmers) Edited.